# Function signature not reflecting as same as in webservice when calling from outside

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, out

I have a web service function as below

```
     public void download_docs(string id,DateTime date,
                               out string error_msg,out int i,
                               out document_dtls document_details)
    {
     //logic     
    }
```

Two In parameters and three OUT parameters.
But when I try to consume the same the function signature is only showing two out parameter as showing in below pic. The first OUT parameter string error_msg is not showing. 
how can show all
[image]

Comment: It has transformed the first out parameter into a return value, it seems, since the signature now has string return value, not void.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks mate..i didn't notice that..

Answer (score 1):

The first `out` parameter is transformed into the return value of the service method. Even though the [WSDL specifcation provides a way](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_parameter) to differentiate return and output parameters, this differentiation is optional. The automatic code generation logic of Visual Studio when creating a service reference does not make this destinction and converts the first `out` parameter to the return value if the service method is `void`. Semantically, the web service call will be exactly the same.